# What is the proper method for embedding multiple truetype fonts in a Winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

This code comes from the most popular answer here: [How to quickly and easily embed fonts in winforms app in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-to-quickly-and-easily-embed-fonts-in-winforms-app-in-c-sharp)

This code works fine except I need to embed multiple fonts. Here is my current code which works:

```
   public partial class UnitInfoBox : Form
{

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr AddFontMemResourceEx(IntPtr pbFont, uint cbFont,
        IntPtr pdv, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] ref uint pcFonts);

    private PrivateFontCollection fonts = new PrivateFontCollection();

    Font Klablasto22, Amaltea14, BauderieScript18, Rudyard22;

    public UnitInfoBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        byte[] fontData = Properties.Resources.klabasto;
        IntPtr fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        uint dummy = 0;
        fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, Properties.Resources.klabasto.Length);
        AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)Properties.Resources.klabasto.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        Klablasto22 = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 24.0F);

        fontData = Properties.Resources.amaltea;
        fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        dummy = 0;
        fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, Properties.Resources.amaltea.Length);
        AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)Properties.Resources.amaltea.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        Amaltea14 = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 14.0F);

        fontData = Properties.Resources.BAUDS_;
        fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, Properties.Resources.BAUDS_.Length);
        AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)Properties.Resources.BAUDS_.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        BauderieScript18 = new Font(fonts.Families[1], 18.0F);

        fontData = Properties.Resources.rudyard;
        fontPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(fontData.Length);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(fontData, 0, fontPtr, fontData.Length);
        fonts.AddMemoryFont(fontPtr, Properties.Resources.rudyard.Length);
        AddFontMemResourceEx(fontPtr, (uint)Properties.Resources.rudyard.Length, IntPtr.Zero, ref dummy);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontPtr);
        Rudyard22 = new Font(fonts.Families[3], 22.0F);
```

Please note that the first font is assigned like so:

```
            Klablasto22 = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 24.0F);
```

But, so is the second font!

```
 Amaltea14 = new Font(fonts.Families[0], 14.0F);
```

Logically, should this be:

```
Amaltea14 = new Font(fonts.Families[1], 14.0F);
```

But, if I do this it pulls in the FIRST FONT! And then the next font is assigned like this:

```
            BauderieScript18 = new Font(fonts.Families[1], 18.0F);
```

And the next font skips two:

```
            Rudyard22 = new Font(fonts.Families[3], 22.0F);
```

This is what I had to do to get the right fonts loaded.

I would really prefer to know how to do this 'the right way'. Does anybody know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: I have been wondering for a while why so many programmers have the exact same bug in their code.  Maybe that post is the evil-doer.  The call to Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() is illegal, the memory allocation must not be released until the font can no longer be used.  Which, realistically, can't be done until after the PrivateFontCollection is disposed, something else that everybody forgets.  Unfortunately programs don't crash often enough, dangling pointer bugs are too hard to diagnose.  But sure, use more than one font and the second font is apt to overwrite the memory used by the first font.

Comment: Thank you for the info. You should write this up as an answer, then I can mark as such, and then other people with this problem will find the solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/17034