# Windows Form font not shown properly in Revit External Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, fonts, revit-api

I am developing a Revit ribbon with some buttons and implemented a windows form in the same solution to show messages regarding the license verification of the ribbon and other stuff.
I am using *Bahnschrift SemiBold SemiConden* font in this windows form but when the form appears in Revit it shows a different one.

Below a caption of the font as shown in Visual Studio:

[image]

Below a caption of what it is shown in Revit:

[image]

As you see the font is not the same. Does anyone have an idea of what is happening? I have searched thoroughly in internet but haven´t found the solution.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not complete, but I think that I know where the problem is and I can tell you how to search for the solution.
The main reason that the font is not showing correctly is that it is a custom font and Revit can't find it on the device you are testing on.
The solution is that you need to get that font, add it to your project as a resource, and then edit your code to search for the font inside the .dll file.
Hope this can help you find a way to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mostafa. I will have a go and will post the solution here if I find it.

Comment: I will be waiting for your results, good luck.

Comment: @angelrps I found this, maybe it will help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23519499/13176802