# Add new font VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a .ttf file that I want to install directly to Visual Studio's fonts for me to use in the future. How can I do it so it shows among the other fonts options?

Comment: If your application is winform, here's a document you can refer to : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-a-private-font-collection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use it in the code editor?

Comment: I want to use it on the design form. I'm sorry, I'm new so I'm not familiar with stuff.

Comment: [How do I embed my own fonts in a WinForms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556147/how-do-i-embed-my-own-fonts-in-a-winforms-app)  It also works in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Alex,

You shouldn't have to install the font in Visual Studio directly, but just on the system Visual Studio is running on.

This codeproject link explains that: [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/157302/Add-new-font-to-VisualStudio-property-window)

I have done this on my own machine as well, where we use a specific barcode font, that I installed on my machine in this manner. So now when I go to a label or textbox -> Font -> The newly added font appears as an option.

Comment: Hello. Where can I find the Control Panel Applet in that case?

Comment: @AlexL You should google for how to install fonts on the version of Windows that you are using.