# How to use custom font for all controls and respecting their own sizes?

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, fonts, font-size

I manage to [embed my own fonts in a WinForms app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23519499/3416774). However the solution provided there requires me to:

- manually apply to individual control, e.g.

  ```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        userControl1.Font = myFont;
        button1.Font = myFont;
    }
  ```
- all of them will have the same size

Is there a way to do this better? Something similar to CSS. I try `Form1.Font = myFont;` but it throws me [Error CS0120](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0120):

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Font'

I put it in the constructor of `Form1` as well, and it builds successfully, but it doesn't change anything on the display.

Is there a way to fix this?